# Can anyone help me check this python code?

Tags: python, algorithm

I met a problem when I want to write a simple permutation code,

```
def permutation(Ori, Curr, used):
  if len(Ori) == len(Curr):
      #print Curr
      return

  for i in xrange(len(Ori)):
      if used[i]:
          continue
      used[i] = True
      Curr.append(Ori[i])
      print Curr,i," after append"
      permutation(Ori, Curr, used)    # further level
      used[i] = False
      print Curr,i," before delete"
      Curr = Curr[0:-1]               # Curr.pop() works
      print Curr,i," after delete"
  return

if __name__ == "__main__":
  used = [False]*3
  Curr = []
  permutation([1,2,3], Curr, used)
```

while result is not correct:

```
[1] 0  after append
[1, 2] 1  after append
[1, 2, 3] 2  after append
[1, 2, 3] 2  before delete
[1, 2] 2  after delete     <------
[1, 2, 3] 1  before delete <------
[1, 2] 1  after delete
[1, 2, 3] 2  after append
[1, 2, 3] 2  before delete
[1, 2] 2  after delete
[1, 2, 3] 0  before delete
[1, 2] 0  after delete
[1, 2, 2] 1  after append
[1, 2, 2] 1  before delete
[1, 2] 1  after delete
[1, 2, 3] 2  after append
[1, 2, 3] 2  before delete
[1, 2] 2  after delete
```

I don't know why the array has an extra number in the step I pointed out.

---

Sorry maybe I haven't made my question clear, I just want to know the reason why that recursion returned a list which I supposed it been shrinked.
I wrote another piece of code, could anyone tell me the difference between the two commented sentence?(A = A[0:-1] and A.pop())

```
def f(A):
     if(len(A) == 10):
         return
     A.append('a')
     f(A)
     print A
 #   A = A[0:-1]                             
 #   A.pop()
     return

 if __name__ == "__main__":
    f([])
```

Comment: you will want to use the code-formatting feature on stackoverflow... unfortunately most likely this question will be closed before you can edit your answer

Comment: additionally you may prefer codereview.stackexchange.com ; questions may be closed if they are too localized and cannot help others in similar situations. you may want to look at http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx . For one thing, there are no comments and no specification, so no one knows what your intent with the function or parameters is

Comment: after posting any question, just look at it that 'if it will be readable/ understandable by others', if not then edit that accordingly..

Comment: I edited your question but I am no familiar with nothing about Python so I hope _while result is not correct:_ is not a part of code :)

Comment: Thanks BurnAfterReading, Im a new comer here, sorry for the former ugly fomat.

Comment: Theres nothing wrong with the question-sense. A person shouldn't be discouraged to post questions, just because he doesn't know how to format it properly. Its rare but not impossible, that people are not familiar with SO culture.

Comment: No problem I have done the same thing in my first question.Welcome to stackoverflow justcoder, try to use the `{}` symbol on the toolbar of asking a question when writing a code block.Good luck.

Comment: I really do not think this question deserved getting closed.

Answer (score 4):

At the line

```
permutation(Ori, Curr, used)    # further level
```

you're passing pointers to the lists, not a copy of the lists. Doing this, when `permutation` modifies `Curr`, you see the modifications in the calling context. One possible solution is to call

```
permutation(Ori, Curr[:], used)    # further level
```

which passes a copy of Curr.

### Why does Curr.pop() work?

Because it modifies `Curr`. It really removes the element from `Curr` before the function returns.

Using `Curr = Curr[0:-1]` creates a copy of `Curr` without one element. The element is not removed from the original list (to which the calling context still has access). So it doesn't do practically anything because the new list without the last element is forgotten as soon as the function returns.

Another possible solution would be not to change the received `Curr` at all - replace

```
Curr.append(Ori[i])
```

with

```
Curr = Curr + [Ori[i]]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is already a function to generate permutations:

http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

The example code (defined in terms of `product`) is the "usual" generator-based implementation in my humble opinion.

In case it is useful to think about, here is code to generate all permutations of an iterable:

```
def permutations(iter):
    """
        >>> print(list( permutations(range(3)) ))
        [[0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2], [1, 2, 0], [2, 0, 1], [2, 1, 0]]
    """
    elements = list(iter)

    # base case
    if len(elements)==0:
        yield []

    for i,elem in enumerate(elements):
        withoutElem = elements[:i]+elements[i+1:]
        for perm in permutations(withoutElem):
            yield [elem]+perm
```

Comment: Thanks ninja, it works. But could you tell me why my code doen't work?